# WHERE IN query in linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
public Class SomeModel
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

this is the method I'm binding values to above model, it contains inline SQL Queries

```
Public ActionResult GetData()
{
  IEnumarable<SomeModel> alltheListValues = ....
}
```

using above method, I want to filter all the record that containing ids in following string.

`string filterIds = "12,13,14,15"`

SomeModel model class `Id` values are in Integer type, but I have string type id set, without going for looping this, I decided to use WHERE IN query to filter this.

since WHERE IN query we can get in Linq as `contains`

I wrote down follwoing function to filter values

```
IEnumarable<SomeModel> filterValues = GetData.Where(Id=> Id.ToString().Contains(filterIds));
```

but this is not selecting any value always zero filter result, how can I wrote this properly

Comment: Is that LINQ query what you're using? Because it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: GetData return ActionResult. How are you able to run Where method on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way to go:

```
string filterIds = "12,13,14,15";

//Convert filterIds string into a integers collection
var ids=filterIds.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);

IEnumarable<SomeModel> filterValues = GetData().Where(sm=> ids.Contains(sm.Id));
```

One thing I noticed now is the signature of your `GetData` method, I think what you mean is:

```
public IEnumarable<SomeModel> GetData()
{
  IEnumarable<SomeModel> alltheListValues = ....
  //...
  return alltheListValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a array/collection instead of a list and check if the id is in it.

```
IEnumarable<SomeModel> filterValues = ActualGetData().Where(n => filterIds.Contains(n.Id))
```

Where ActualGetData() returns you an IEnumarable.
In your current code GetData() returns an ActionResult as Drew Kennedy mentioned

Comment: Two things wrong, and it's more to do with the question. 1) GetData is a function, so it would need the parenthesis. 2) It returns ActionResult, so this wouldn't compile anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all the elements of collection of "Id" will be convertible to number then you can use following approach.

```
var models = new List<SomeModel>(); //Consider that this collection is coming from some service or repository.
var Ids = filterIds.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));
IEnumarable<SomeModel> filterValues = models.Where(n => Ids.Contains(n.Id));
```

Your code wound't compile so I am posting here just the logical code here. You can use it as per your requirement.

Comment: actually this string to integer conversion is wrong there for getting an exception, anyway thanks for the support!